# Immutable/ephemeral W10 desktops

Tags: windows, pxe-boot, provisioning, guest, immutable

(As reader may guess, I'm more familiar & comfortable in the Linux/POSIX world, so please keep that in mind)

I'm in the process of rebuiling n+20 laptops, intended for semi-public use (MakerSpace: think classroom or library), and want to set them up in an immutable/ephemeral manner.

I want them to be 'flushed' periodically, so that they are all similar/standard, and clean for the next persons' use.

Users/guests constantly log into the desktops an/or browsers with their personal gmail/o365 accounts, which has us/my environ represent a privacy & security risk.

The game-plan looks like:

- set up a base-line or reference (W10) desktop with

  - stripped-down OS, with updates , patches & system-level tweaks applied
  - relevant accounts loaded - logons & browsers logged into relevant web-apps (cookies loaded), etc
  - using the likes winget, choco/vagrant/ansible/puppet/chef/whatever/etc to install our standard app set
- setting up local server/'cloud' back-end for docker/VM's/etc to rapidly try out options

  - PXE imaging & deployment tool - Foreman, FOG, etc
  - Guests/users store configs & personal data on LAN NAS (ala NextCloud)
- image or build periodic reference snapshot of reference-machines (including updates) that get deplyed via PXE

Essentially what I'm after is something akin to [Fedora Silverblue](https://getfedora.org/en/silverblue/), that's an immutable/ephemeral desktop, where nothing "sticks" across reboots & the underlying remains unchanged. Thinkig of it in a similar way Docker images have changes "layered" on top of each other or a ZFS or Git, where changes are taken as incremental snapshots that can be committed or rolled back gracefully.

I/we have not comitted to AD yet - the environment has not been large or complex enough to warrant it yet - but I know the short answer is to use GPO; I plan on burning that bridge eventually.

Is there a way or some other best-practice means for me to achive this goal?
How can I build an OS or image that gets nuked - from the ground up - across reboots, to the point where the HDD's are interchangable & no update are ever promped?

Comment: 20+ years ago, my community college solved this problem by reimaging the entire system on login

Comment: One way could be to boot them over iSCSI with CoW and drop snapshots on reboot.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a *kiosk* station.

Microsoft has the [Unified Write Filter module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/unified-write-filter) for that.

HP thin clients for example come with this installed and a little user interface to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I have used a program called DeepFreeze to lock the state of the computer.
Fixes a lot of the issues you asked about but there are other issues that can arrise.
You can disable through group policy the setting that allows personal accounts, but I do believe they need to be on win pro.
If you have not settled on AD, you could also use the free accounts of a MS O365 domain to manage users.
You can create a test tennant here, but note that at minimum you would need 1 O365 Business Basic account ~$7 CAD per month.
Only one user needs to be registered to create other users for domain based login.
https://signup.microsoft.com/create-account/signup?OfferId=B07A1127-DE83-4a6d-9F85-2C104BDAE8B4&dl=ENTERPRISEPACK&ali=1&products=cfq7ttc0k59j:0009